# How to get the "Sunburner" achievement in Kingdom Rush

Tags: achievements, kingdom-rush

How do I get the "Sunburner" achievement in Kingdom Rush on Android if the Sunray is broken? I know that isn't possible use, but some people earned this achievement, and I want to find out how.

Comment: Hi Quobbs, I edited your post to make it a little clearer, but don't know what you mean with "that isn't possible use". Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

You must acess the beta version of update (you must participate the beta program of google play) and play the stage, there is this tower.

Answer (score 1):

The Sunray is not broken, **it's unavailable on Android**, according to [the wiki entry of the Sunray Tower](https://kingdomrushtd.fandom.com/wiki/Sunray_Tower). Hence the 'Sunburner!' achievement cannot be earned.

Comment: Don't worry. i discovered how. You must acess the beta version of update (you must participate the beta program of google play) and play the stage, there is this tower.